# Ruby on Rails: I want to create a sponsor_id which must be exist in User.id exept the first User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Hi I am creating my `User` which the `User` requirements are: 
1. to have a `User.sponsor_id` with an exeption of the first user does not require to have a `sponsor_id`.
2. the sponsor_id must be exist on User.

I have this code right now for the `model/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :sponsor, class_name: "User"

  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save {email.downcase!} 
  validates :first_name, :presence =>true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :last_name, :presence => true, length: {maximum: 50}
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, :presence =>true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_nil:true
  validates :sponsor, presence:true 
  validate :sponsor_id_valid

  .
  .
  .

  def first_user
    return true if User.count==0
    return true if persisted&& self.id== User.first.id
    return false
  end

  def sponsor_id_valid
    return if first_user
    unless self.class.find_by(id: sponsor_id)
      errors.add(:sponsor_id, "does not exist")
    end
  end
end
```

And I have this code for my db/migrate/...usertable.rb

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email, unique: true
      t.integer :sponsor_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :users, :sponsor_id
  end
end
```

And this is my `db/seeds.rb` file

```
User.delete_all
User.create!(first_name: "Test",
            last_name: "User",
            email: "test@user.com",
            password: "password",
            password_confirmation: "password",
            sponsor_id: 1 )
10.times do |n|
  first_name = Faker::Name.name
  last_name=Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@user.com"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(first_name: first_name,
               last_name: last_name,
               email: email,
               password: password,
               password_confirmation: password,
               sponsor_id:test.id )
end
```

The test code I want to past is in `test/model/users.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
      @user=User.first
      @user2=User.new(
      first_name: "Test2", 
      last_name: "User2", 
      email: "user2@test.com", 
      sponsor_id: @user.id,
      password:"foobar",
      password_confirmation:"foobar") 
      @user2.save

  end

  test "1. should be valid" do
    byebug
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "2. First name should be present" do 
    @user.first_name = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "3. Last name should be present" do 
    @user.last_name=""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "4. email should be present" do
    @user.email=""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "5. sponsor_id should be present" do
    @user2.sponsor_id= nil
    assert_not @user2.valid?
  end

  test "6.name should not be too long" do
    @user.first_name= "a" * 52
    @user.last_name="a" * 52
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "7. email should not be too long " do
    @user.email="a" * 244+ "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "8.email validation should accept valid addresses" do 
    valid_addresses= %w[userunique@test.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@bax.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid" 
    end
  end

  test "9. email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com foo@bar..com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
   end
  end

  test "10. Email addresses should be unique" do 
    duplicate_user=@user.dup
    duplicate_user.email= @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end


  test "11. password should be present (nonblank" do 
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " * 6
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "12. password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "13. email addresses should be saved as lower-case" do
    mixed_case_email = "PEaK@ExAMPle.CoM"
    @user.email = mixed_case_email
    @user.save
    assert_equal mixed_case_email.downcase, @user.reload.email
      end

  test "14.sponsor_id must be presence" do 
    @user2.sponsor_id= nil 
    assert_not @user2.valid?
  end

  test "15. the sponsor_id must be the existing id" do
    @user2.sponsor_id = 1000
    assert_not @user2.valid?
  end

  test "16. authenticated? should return false for a suer with nil digest" do
    assert_not @user.authenticated?('')
  end


end
```

When I run `rake db:seed` it always said I have wrong argument 
Can anyone help me? Please advise.

This is the full error message :

```
$ rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Sponsor can't be blank
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
/Users/peakdrum/workspace/Goldshape/db/seeds.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/peakdrum/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Thanks in advance

PS @RichPeck (I don't know how to tag) but this is the upgraded version

Answer (score 0):

The error in `rake db:seed` is probably with `test.id` since there's nowhere in the seeds.rb file that you assign anything to a variable `test`

I'd suggest you first change your validations

```
validate :sponsor_id_valid

def first_user
  return true if User.count == 0 
  return true if persisted? && self.id == User.first.id
  return false
end

def sponsor_id_valid
  return if first_user
  unless self.class.find_by(id: sponsor_id)
    errors.add(:sponsor_id, "does not exist")
  end      
end
```

Then in the seeds file change the first lines to...

```
User.delete_all
test = User.create!(first_name: "Test",
...
```

And when posting a question always give the full text of the error message.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I tried your code and this error occur: 
`rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!`

Comment: I already post the full error message in the original post thanks

Comment: So there's pending migrations. So do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: In your code should persisted has a question mark at the end ?

Comment: @PeakSornpaisarn exactly right, well spotted.  I've now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`User.count!=User.first` will not quite work since its a poor comparison. You are comparing `User.first.to_i` (which is the id of the first user) to a count of the number of records in the Users table. This is a Catch-22 condition since it will only be equal if the is one record in the table and it has the id 1. Which means that you cannot create the first record.

Instead if you want to check if a user is the first user you would do it like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :sponsor, unless: :first? 

  # ...
  def first?
    if persisted?
      User.first == self
    else
      !User.any?
    end
  end
end
```